# Self Oscillating INA with Multiple Feedback filter

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, active-filter

I'm working on a circuit to receive a signal in the 220Hz range.  The signal is created from a small loop transmitter emitting a 50% duty cycle DC square wave of about 4.8 Watts.

The receiver is a small loop antenna (4.69 Henries) with a 0.11uF tuning cap, which should tune the receiver to about 221 Hz.

The problem is when I disconnect both the transmitter and receivers from the circuit, I still get a half wave (positive phase) of about 103Hz. I presume that is some self-resonating characteristic of the circuit.  Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong with this circuit?  Shunting the inputs significantly reduces the 103Hz output, but does not eliminate it.

Noise does not appear to be coming through the power supply, however I have also added a 1.2uF cap/ferrite bead filter between the +/- sources to GND. (not shown)

Ideally I'd like to have the output produce near 0V when the inputs are shorted together.

Note: the diode D3 is strictly for clipping the negative output portion of the wave, as the output goes to an ADS1015 ADC converter, which is not a bipolar ADC.

All components except R1 and R2 (Trimpots) are 1% tolerance.

[image]

Comment: Yes the frequencies are correct.  It's not a wireless communication system.  It's for reading changes in electromagnetic fields caused by varying conductivity.  It's a proven analog system that works.

Comment: Okay. I don't have any advice to give, I just wanted to make sure you didn't mean kHz or anything.

Comment: the 4.69H small loop antenna sounds innovative.  Can you show a photo of it with a piece of measuring tape in the same image just for size reference?

Comment: @user287001, it is innovative and for now unpatented, so I can't share that secret yet.  :)  But it measures 200mm in diameter and works like a charm.  The system works, but it's more noisy than it should be and part of that noise, I suspect, is coming from the self-oscillation problem without the TX/RX hooked up.

Comment: A common source of 100 Hz is rectified AC mains voltage - are you in a 50 Hz area?

Comment: @Andyaka, No, I'm in the US, so 60 Hz has been my most challenging problem.  That's actually why I went with the active filter design to begin with.  I'm not discounting the possibility that it could be some AC noise causing the issue and I've pondered the values of R3 and R4, which as I understand it, are primarily responsible for the attenuation of AC noise in inamps.  I've tried several values for these resistors from 46k up to 1Meg and the range of 634k seemed to provide the best overall results.

Comment: Note that "low-noise" inamps and opamps tend to have an inherently high input capacitance.